# Using RTC_WAKEUP with Xamarin

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android, alarmmanager

I am using Xamarin for android and I would like to use the RTC_WAKEUP flag for setting an alarm.  Does anyone know how to calculate the trigger time in milliseconds?  I can use
DateTime.ToUniversalTime, however the alarmmanager set method is looking for a long (milliseconds).

For elapsed time I can use
SystemClock.ElapsedRealtime()

But the documentation for RTC_WAKEUP says to use System.currentTimeMillis().  I cannot find the equivalent in c#.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

In Xamarin Android you can use `Java.Lang.JavaSystem.CurrentTimeMillis();`

Example how to set up an Wakup Alarm at 18:30:

```
Java.Util.Calendar calendar = Java.Util.Calendar.Instance;
calendar.Set(CalendarField.HourOfDay, 18);
calendar.Set(CalendarField.Minute, 30);
alarmManager.SetRepeating(AlarmType.RtcWakeup, calendar.TimeInMillis, AlarmManager.IntervalDay, pendingAlarmIntent);
```

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't find a built in method, but the number of milliseconds since 1970 is easy enough to calculate.  The following works for me, and wakes the machine at the right time:

```
DateTime dtBasis = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc); // Android times are quoted as milliseconds since start of 1970
alarm_manager.Set(AlarmType.RtcWakeup, (long)wake_up_at.ToUniversalTime().Subtract(dtBasis).TotalMilliseconds, my_intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the **ToUnixTimeMilliseconds()** extension of the DateTimeOffset class.

```
long trigger = new DateTimeOffset(triggerDate).ToUnixTimeMilliseconds();
```